# ¿Cómo configurar classpath en Netbeans?

Tags: java, xml, netbeans, java-ee

Buenos dias el motivo de mi pregunta es sobre como configurar classpath en Netbeans(8.2), ya que estoy creando un proyecto aplicación web (con **jee 7web** )pero al momento de ejecutar el proyecto me generaba un error de librería que me faltaba  **javaee-endorsed-api-7.0** al momento de agregar la librería ejecuto nuevamente el código   pero al momento de agregar me sale un error sobre el xml indicando, lo unico que tengo en el proyecto es el index de hola mundo que crea el programa por defecto

```html
< target name = "-init-taskdefs" >
  <  fail unless = "libs.CopyLibs.classpath" >
  The libs.CopyLibs.classpath property is not set up.
This property must point to
org - netbeans - modules - java - j2seproject - copylibstask.jar file which is part of NetBeans IDE installation and is usually located at &
  lt;
netbeans_installation & gt;
/java&lt;version&gt;/ant / extra folder.
Either open the project in the IDE and make sure CopyLibs library
exists or setup the property manually.For example like this:
  ant - Dlibs.CopyLibs.classpath = a / path / to / org - netbeans - modules - java - j2seproject - copylibstask.jar <
  /fail> <  taskdef classpath = "${libs.CopyLibs.classpath}"resource = "org/netbeans/modules/java/j2seproject/copylibstask/antlib.xml" / >
  <  /target>
```

**Al momento de ejecutar me indica el siguiente error**

> ant -f "G:\Mis Documentos\NetBeansProjects\WebServiceSicb" -Dnb.internal.action.name=build -DforceRedeploy=false "-Dbrowser.context=G:\Mis Documentos\NetBeansProjects\WebServiceSicb" dist G:\Mis Documentos\NetBeansProjects\WebServiceSicb\nbproject\build-impl.xml:797: The libs.CopyLibs.classpath property is not set up. This property must point to org-netbeans-modules-java-j2seproject-copylibstask.jar file which is part of NetBeans IDE installation and is usually located at /java/ant/extra folder. Either open the project in the IDE and make sure CopyLibs library exists or setup the property manually. For example like this: ant -Dlibs.CopyLibs.classpath=a/path/to/org-netbeans-modules-java-j2seproject-copylibstask.jar BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dale click derecho al proyecto, selecciona propiedades, luego Run, y allí veras un recuadro llamado Arguments....ese lo tienes que llenar con los parámetros de interés.